# How do export js2shapefile as zip file?

Tags: javascript, export, shapefile, jszip, filesaver.js

I'm developing a gis application. I want to export a layer to `shape file` in javascript using [js2Shapefile](https://github.com/borisdev/js2shapefile).

`js2Shapefile` uses [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) for exporting.

`FileSaver` exports 3 files (`.shp`, `.shx` and `.dbf`) separately. I'd like the exported files to be zipped in a single file.

How do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is adding another library an option to you, I think you can use the lib JSZip for zipping files.

See details:  https://stuk.github.io/jszip/